# label inside input using jquery

Tags: jquery, input, label

my "label" is inside the input, so i want to empty the field when the user click and if its empty the "label" is back again

```
     $('#name').focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val()=="Your name") { $(this).val(""); }
    }).blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val()=="") { $(this).val("Your name") }
    });
```

and this would be done to 3 or more fields, there's any better aprouch? without using plugins, just jquery

Comment: You also need to account for what happens if they leave the field blank and submit the form.

Comment: its a ajax reply, i do php validation only in this case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120257/what-is-the-best-html5-placeholder-like-jquery-plugin-out-there/5120428#5120428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it work with the other fields easily you could remove the check and place the `Your name` value on the title attribute of the field.

```
$('.waterMarkInput').focus(function() {
  if ($(this).val()==$(this).attr("title")) { $(this).val(""); }
}).blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val()=="") { $(this).val($(this).attr("title")); }
});
```

And then your input fields could look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="waterMarkInput" title="Your name"/>
```

Comment: thanks! a little fix: if ($(this).val()=="") { $(this).val($(this).attr("title")); }

Comment: I started with this script and added the ability to simply use the current value of the field, so there is no need to have a title attribute. Also added the necessary deferred executiion. <pre> $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.inlineLabel').focus(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("initial") == undefined) {
   $(this).attr("initial",$(this).val());
  }
  if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("initial")) {
   $(this).val("");
  }
 }).blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
   $(this).val($(this).attr("initial"));
  }
 });
 });
</pre>

Answer (score 5):

I think your method is probably almost as concise as it's going to get, but it's worth noting that html5 offers the [`placeholder`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute to `input` tags:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name." />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2KRVU/1/).

This is, of course, [yet to make its way through to the non-modern browsers...](http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/)